# How many local maxima can a polynomial of even degree have?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$. 
I'm sure this is easy, but how many local maxima can $f$ have, at most?
(The limits are going to $\infty$)

Comment: Well, $f'$ can have at most $2n-1$ roots, so $f$ can have at most $2n-1$ critical points.  If we assume the lead coefficient is negative, then the first is a maximum, so...

Comment: If you are struggling to work straight to a final solution directly., then consider some examples.  You know what the quintessential degree $2$ polynomial looks like... How many local maxima are there at most for a parabola?  Now, how about for a quartic?  Try to spot a pattern and see if your pattern is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there can be at most $2n-1$ stationary points as the derivative is a $2n-1$ degree polynomial. Also note that we cannot have two consecutive maxima. So the most maxima is achieved when we alternate max and min, with maximum starting first, i.e. $n$ such maxima.